# Having problems compiling an example in the boost Logging Tutorial

Tags: logging, boost, timestamp

I am having a problem building the following code from the boost tutorial.
Here is the link to the boost tutorial and example code:
https://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html

```cpp
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
```

Here is the build error

```
/local/include/boost/log/utility/setup/formatter_parser.hpp:207: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatter<char> boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::parse_formatter<char>(char const*, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I comment out the the following line from the code above it will build fine.

```cpp
keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"
```

So it appears to be something on that particular line that is causing the build failure.

I also added the following include I found in another posting on this site.
This did not help either.

[Compilation error with Boost log library when using date_time_formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523113/compilation-error-with-boost-log-library-when-using-date-time-formatter)

```cpp
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
```

Comment: Did you use the ["See the complete code"](https://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_fmt_stream.cpp) link? It compiles and links just fine here. The error you show is a linker error. Did you link the required libraries? There's also a FAQ: https://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale.html

Comment: Thank you for the help. The example I used was different than the one you suggested. I just used the one you suggested and it worked fine.  Thank you again!